# Nested if's - what's more Pythonic?

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, indentation, pep

Both functions do the same thing.

```
def function1(self):
    a = self.get_a()
    b = self.get_b()
    c = self.get_c()
    r = None

    if a:
        r = a
        if b:
            r = b
            if c:
                r = c
            else:
                print("c not set.")
        else:
            print("b not set.")
    else:
        print("a not set.")

    return r



def function2(self):
    a = self.get_a()
    b = self.get_b()
    c = self.get_c()
    r = None

    if not a:
        print("a not set.")
        return r

    r = a
    if not b:
        print("b not set.")
        return r

    r = b
    if not c:
        print("c not set.")

    r = c
    return r
```

function1() creates very long lines the more if's are nested which conflicts with PEP8's line-length limit of 78.

function2() might be harder to read/understand and has more return statements. Line length is no problem here.

Which one is more pythonic?

Comment: You can also get rid of `r` and directly return `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Comment: If you don't need the `print` calls in the `else` branches, you could do the whole computation in one go, with `a and (b and c or b) or a or None`. The `or None` at the end is only necessary if the potential "falsey" values you're testing for are not limited to None (and you care about actually returning `None` instead of some other falsey thing).

Comment: @Blckknght I actually didn't see your comment before I submitted, if you want to submit it as an answer I will delete mine.

Comment: Well, acutally these functions act differently in case that a and b are true, but c is false ;-) Cf. my answer for a comparison and some patterns you might use to be PEP8 conform and have readable, explicit and extensible implementation. Happy python learning to us all ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the principals of Pythonic code is "flat is better than nested". On this basis, I'll say `function2()` is objectively more Pythonic. This can be seen in [PEP-20: The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> **The Zen of Python**
>
> ```
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
> Explicit is better than implicit.
> Simple is better than complex.
> Complex is better than complicated.
> Flat is better than nested.
> Sparse is better than dense.
> Readability counts.
> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
> Although practicality beats purity.
> Errors should never pass silently.
> Unless explicitly silenced.
> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
> Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
> Now is better than never.
> Although never is often better than *right* now.
> If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
> If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
> ```

This can be seen by typing `import this` inside the Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the `import this`. I've actually never seen this

Answer (score 2):

As @Will's answer suggests, flat is better. However the code doesn't look very pretty anyways. How about a more compact type of code?

looking at these quotes from @Will's answer:

> Readability counts.
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def function3():
    my_dictionary=OrderedDict()
    my_dictionary['a'] = self.get_a()
    my_dictionary['b'] = self.get_b()
    my_dictionary['c'] = self.get_c()
    # ...
    r = None

    for name in my_dictionary.keys():
        value = my_dictionary[name]
        if not value:
            print("%s not set." % name)
            return r
        r = value
    return r
```

Surely this can be improved even more

Comment: But the behaviours of function_1, function_2 and function_3 are all pair wise different ;-) cf. my proposed answer's test results

Comment: Oh, forgot a last `return` to match funct1. I guess it's about the principle anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can use the evaluation rules of the `and` and `or` operators, for example:

```
>>> None or 4 or None or 5
4

>>> 4 and 5
5
```

So you'd have something like:

```
def function3(self):
    a = self.get_a()
    b = self.get_b()
    c = self.get_c()
    return (a and b and c) or (a and b) or a or None
```

And I'd recommend factoring out you I/O from your logical code.

Comment: Readability is important and extensibility - if it would remain 3 request dimensions and one default for ever, the combined logical onliner that you suggest would be my favourite, but on my planet over the last decades it almost always needed extension of dimensions like another sensor, another attribute, and that suggests one to sooner or later declare an ordering, pick matching containers and than iterate over these ...

Comment: @Dilettant I'd think it would be pretty straightforward to extend this into a general case with some generator-expression magic. Like: `reduce(lambda a, b: a or b, [reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, vals[:i]) for i in range(1,len(vals)+1)], None)` where `vals` contains the list of values you're interested in. Or something like that anyway I haven't thought it through in depth.

Comment: There was a reason, why reduce vanished from builtins in Python3 ;-) in the context of the samples given in this page, which all claimed to be functionally equivalent and mostly were not, it is clear, how easy convoluted (deeply nested function_1), copy-paste-like (function_2), essentially one-liners (your suggestion) are hard to compare, ensure as equal and all carry additional weight in maintenance ... and I understood the OP to be at the beginning of the journey to Python mastery.

Comment: @Dilettant I'll admit your point rings true. To be fair you kind of backed me into a premature-refactoring corner... I only did it with a one-liner `reduce` expression because I was coming up with something off the top of my head for the comments section. My main point with this answer was that it's often possible to take care of your logic without resorting to explicit conditionals. I was trying to emphasize that pretty much any program has a functional core that can be expressed elegantly just using expressions (and typically in python, a healthy dose of `itertools`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest function_4 displayed below together with the questions (non-idetnically working!) functions and one of DomTomCat's answer:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import OrderedDict  # Only used in function_3


def function_4(self):
    """Iterate over call results in FIFO on False or if sequence
    exhausted, return None or previous value if that evaluates to true."""

    functors = (
        self.get_a,
        self.get_b,
        self.get_c,
    )
    request_targets = (
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
    )
    response_value = None
    for functor, request_target in zip(functors, request_targets):
        current_response = functor()
        if not current_response:
            print(request_target, "not set.")
            return response_value
        else:
            response_value = current_response

    return response_value


class Foo(object):
    """Mock the thingy ..."""
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._a, self._b, self._c = a, b, c

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            "Foo(" + str(self._a) + ", " + str(self._b) + ", " +
            str(self._c) + ")")

    def get_a(self):
        return self._a

    def get_b(self):
        return self._b

    def get_c(self):
        return self._c


def function_1(self):
    a = self.get_a()
    b = self.get_b()
    c = self.get_c()
    r = None

    if a:
        r = a
        if b:
            r = b
            if c:
                r = c
            else:
                print("c not set.")
        else:
            print("b not set.")
    else:
        print("a not set.")

    return r


def function_2(self):
    a = self.get_a()
    b = self.get_b()
    c = self.get_c()
    r = None

    if not a:
        print("a not set.")
        return r

    r = a
    if not b:
        print("b not set.")
        return r

    r = b
    if not c:
        print("c not set.")

    r = c
    return r


def function_3(self):
    my_dictionary = OrderedDict()
    my_dictionary['a'] = self.get_a()
    my_dictionary['b'] = self.get_b()
    my_dictionary['c'] = self.get_c()
    # ...
    r = None

    for name in my_dictionary.keys():
        value = my_dictionary[name]
        if not value:
            print("%s not set." % name)
            return r
        r = value


def main():
    """"Drive the investigation."""
    fixtures = (
        (1, 42, 3.1415),
        (0, 42, 3.1415),
        (1, 0, 3.1415),
        (1, 42, 0),
    )
    functors = (
        function_1,
        function_2,
        function_3,
        function_4,
    )
    for fixture in fixtures:
        foo = Foo(*fixture)
        print("\nFixture:", foo)
        for i, functor in enumerate(functors, start=1):
            print("Functor[%d]:" % (i,))
            print(functor(foo))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On my machine the fixtures produce the following behaviour/output when being called:

```
Fixture: Foo(1, 42, 3.1415)
Functor[1]:
3.1415
Functor[2]:
3.1415
Functor[3]:
None
Functor[4]:
3.1415

Fixture: Foo(0, 42, 3.1415)
Functor[1]:
a not set.
None
Functor[2]:
a not set.
None
Functor[3]:
a not set.
None
Functor[4]:
a not set.
None

Fixture: Foo(1, 0, 3.1415)
Functor[1]:
b not set.
1
Functor[2]:
b not set.
1
Functor[3]:
b not set.
1
Functor[4]:
b not set.
1

Fixture: Foo(1, 42, 0)
Functor[1]:
c not set.
42
Functor[2]:
c not set.
0
Functor[3]:
c not set.
42
Functor[4]:
c not set.
42
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do without removing the print statements

```py
def function1(self):
    a = self.get_a()
    b = self.get_b()
    c = self.get_c()
    r = None

    inputValues = [a, b, c]
    setValues = [i for i in inputValues if i]
    for index, value in inputValues:
        if len(setValues) <= index or setValues[index] != value:
            print(f'{value} is not set.')
        else:
            r = value
    return r
```

The `function2` looks good enough to go.